# ExtJS: store.load() doesn't load data

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4.2

I'm faced with problem in ExtJS 4.2, that store.load() method doesn't load data from server, only retrieve json.
My **js/itfx/resources/genres.json** file:

```
[{"name":"Action & Adventure","code":"ACTION-ADVENTURE-00"},{"name":"African","code":"AFRICAN-00"},{"name":"Anime","code":"ANIME-00"},{"name":"Bollywood","code":"BOLLYWOOD-00"},{"name":"Classics","code":"CLASSICS-00"},{"name":"Comedy","code":"COMEDY-00"},{"name":"Concert Films","code":"CONCERT-FILMS-00"},{"name":"Documentary","code":"DOCUMENTARY-00"},{"name":"Drama","code":"DRAMA-00"},{"name":"Foreign","code":"FOREIGN-00"},{"name":"Holiday","code":"HOLIDAY-00"},{"name":"Horror","code":"HORROR-00"},{"name":"Independent","code":"INDEPENDENT-00"},{"name":"Kids & Family","code":"KIDS-FAMILY-00"},{"name":"Made for TV","code":"MADE-FOR-TV-00"},{"name":"Middle Eastern","code":"MIDDLE-EASTERN-00"},{"name":"Music Documentaries","code":"MUSIC-DOCUMENTARIES-00"},{"name":"Music Feature Film","code":"MUSIC-FEATURE-FILMS-00"},{"name":"Musicals","code":"MUSICALS-00"},{"name":"Regional Indian","code":"REGIONAL-INDIAN-00"},{"name":"Romance","code":"ROMANCE-00"},{"name":"Russian","code":"RUSSIAN-00"},{"name":"Sci-Fi & Fantasy","code":"SCIFI-FANTASY-00"},{"name":"Short Films","code":"SHORT-FILMS-00"},{"name":"Special Interest","code":"SPECIAL-INTEREST-00"},{"name":"Sports","code":"SPORTS-00"},{"name":"Thriller","code":"THRILLER-00"},{"name":"Turkish","code":"TURKISH-00"},{"name":"Urban","code":"URBAN-00"},{"name":"Western","code":"WESTERN-00"}]
```

My model:

```
Ext.define('ITFX.model.films.info.FilmGenre', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'code', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

My store:

```
Ext.define('ITFX.store.films.info.FilmGenre', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    model: 'ITFX.model.films.info.FilmGenre',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'js/itfx/resources/genres.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

So, after execute code abowe:

```
var allFilmGenresStore = Ext.create('ITFX.store.films.info.FilmGenre');
allFilmGenresStore.load();
```

Methods

```
allFilmGenresStore.getCount(); //0
allFilmGenresStore.getTotalCount(); //0
```

will return, that store have nothing loaded
What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any errors in chrome developer tools console?  If you look at the XHR request in chrome developer tools do you see the actual ajax request happen?

Comment: Are you waiting for the calls for the data to complete?  Ajax is asynchronous and you can't run allFilmGenresStore.getCount() right after allFilmGenresStore.load() because the data may not have returned from the server yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks for assist, the rout cause was, that store data loaded asynchronously. Code for load data, should be:

```
allFilmGenresStore.load({ 
    callback : function(records, options, success) { 
        // some custom logik 
    } 
});
```

Comment: You can also add listener on the store 'load' event to do something with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change reader

```
reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'root'
        }
```

and to send `json_encode('root' => $data);`

I hope it will help you